# Вызов javascript функции на максимально раннем этапе загрузки страницы

Tags: javascript

При каждой загрузке страницы, я получаю разрешение экрана пользователя и передаю его на сервер функцией

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var w=window.screen.width;
   remoteLayoutPage([{name: 'scrWidth', value: w}]);
});
```

Проблема в том, что эта функция ждет загрузку всей страницы, и только затем вызывается. Я не могу ждать, пока прогрузятся все элементы страницы, для меня это слишком долго. Мне нужно как можно раньше узнать разрешение экрана устройства пользователя и передать его на сервер. Как возможно решить этот вопрос. Может есть какая-то функция вместо `$(document).ready`, например `$(document).startload`...

Comment: самая быстрая - это вообще ни во что не оборачивать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//$(document).ready(function() {
   var w=window.screen.width;
   remoteLayoutPage([{name: 'scrWidth', value: w}]);
//});
```